# Weird behaviour with controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, extends

In my current application, I've some functionality that are shared by all the UIViewControllers, like HUDs, connectivity library, tab gesture, and so on.
I've thought that a good way to avoid repeating code, would be to create a controller called `"BaseViewController"` with this attributes and methods, and all the normal `UIViewControllers` are extending it. I thought that this would be a good approach.
Also all this controllers are grouped by a tab bar and preceded sometimes by nav bars.

(1) TabBar

(1.1)Controller_*(1.2)NavBar****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**(1.3)NavBar_***_*__*_*__*_*__**(1.4)Controller

```
            (1.2.1)Controller____(1.3.1)Controller

            (1.2.1.1)Controller__(1.3.1.1)Controller
```

The problem comes when I would like to show a popup when one of the tabs is pressed, asking for a pin. This functionality is implemented in BaseViewController inside `-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController` method.

In general there's no problem, but after visiting some deep controllers like (1.2.1.1) or (1.3.1.1), the popups are trying to be shown always in there, even this view are not currently being shown.

Is like, all the `UIViewControllers` where sharing the same instance of `BaseViewController`, and the last being created is the one always being called.

So maybe there is something about Objective C I'm not currently understanding, and what would be the solution to that?

**EDIT**

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{


    UIViewController *destController = viewController;
    if ([destController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        destController = [((UINavigationController *) viewController) topViewController];
    }

    if (![destController isKindOfClass:[TransactionsListViewController class]] && ![destController isKindOfClass:[BalanceViewController class]]) {
        return YES;
    }

    User *user = [DPreferences getCurrentUser];

    if ([user didPinExpired]) {
        PinPopUpViewController *pinVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PinPopUpViewController"];

        self.pinPopViewController = pinVC;

        [pinVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 200)];
        pinVC.mTag = k_BaseViewController_PinTransactionList;
        pinVC.delegate = self;

        [self presentPopupViewController:pinVC animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];

        return NO;
    } else {

        return YES;
    }

}
```

I'm using MJPopup lib to show popup view, that to look for the top view uses this method:

```
-(UIView*)topView {
    UIViewController *recentView = self;

    while (recentView.parentViewController != nil) {
        recentView = recentView.parentViewController;
    }
    return recentView.view;
}
```

Comment: include shouldSelectViewController code

Comment: Sorry, I was setting tab bar delegate to "self", in every controller (BaseViewController viewDidLoad), so the last one to be created (usually the deepest), was getting the tab bar call, causing the problem.